# Performing isnull in string

Tags: c#, null

How do I check if a string is null and set it to some value if it is?

Like in SQL,

```
isnull(string, 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string myString = null;
string isNullString = myString == null ? "0" : myString;
```

Answer (score 13):

You could test for null:

```
if (s == null)
   s = "Hello";
```

or use the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

```
string null_s = null;
string non_null_s = null_s ?? "Hello";
```

---

If you want to catch empty strings too, then you could use the IsNullOrEmpty test:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
   s = "Hello";
```

Comment: A little side note, `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` would mean you can't use `??`, only the if statement (or if-else).

Comment: as another side note, if you're asking questions about "null", then it might be worth spending a little time on a C# primer/tutorial - just so you can understand the basics of what C# means by objects, references, instances, etc - each language is different (SQL is very different to C#) and reading up on a few basics might save you some from some frustration.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .Net 4.0 you can use [string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) method also.